# how to delete folders from cloudinary media library?

Tags: node.js, graphql, cloudinary

I want to delete those folders which don't have any asset.

currenly, I saved images in cloudinary like this project/uuid/image.

I use this api method `cloudinary.api.delete_resources_by_prefix` to delete the assets from UUID folder, the image is deleted from cloudinary media library but empty folders exist.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_folder), there is a `delete_folder` method.

So with Node, you can do something like this:

```
cloudinary.v2.api.delete_folder("project/uuid", console.log);
```

Comment: apparently, if you call this right after `cloudinary.api.delete_resources_by_prefix` it's going to answer  `{ message: 'Folder is not empty', http_code: 400 }`.

Comment: I use the same function but my app crashed, while the 'Folder is empty message' is returned. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Cloudinary rename moved files from temporary folder of user to my desire folder. After that, i would remove the temporary folder and all files inside.

I found a solution i combined delete_ressources_by_prefix and delete_folder after my "rename" promise. Additionnaly, i updated informations for my mongo DB

```
                   arrayPics = req.body.pics

                   let res_promises = arrayPics.map(pic => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                       
                       cloudinary.uploader.rename(`productPics/tmp-${req.user._id}/${pic.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]}`,
                       `productPics/${doc._id}/${pic.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]}`,function(err,result){
                           console.log(err)
                           resolve()
                       })
                   }))

                   Promise.all(res_promises).then(()=>{
                       cloudinary.api.delete_resources_by_prefix(`productPics/tmp-${req.user._id}`,function(err,result){
                               console.log(err)
                           cloudinary.api.delete_folder(`productPics/tmp-${req.user._id}`,function(err,result){
                               console.log(err)
                           });
                       })
                           for(let i=0;i<arrayPics.length;i++){
                               arrayPics[i] = arrayPics[i].replace(arrayPics[i].split('/').reverse()[1],doc._id)
                           }

                           products.update(
                               {_id: doc._id},
                               {$set: {images: arrayPics}}
                           )
                           res.send(doc._id)
                   })
```